# VueJS Migration from 2X to 3X Not Working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vuejs-transition

I'm trying to convert a legacy app from Vue 2 to Vue 3. I'm not super familiar with Vue, I'm trying to follow the new migration template they provide on their docs website but I'm running into issues. I'm not getting any JS console errors, but my Vue code is no longer rendering anymore.

**Existing Code**

```html
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            applications: []
        },
        created: function () {
            console.log('Vue App Created'); 
            this.loadModel();
        },
        methods:
        {
            loadModel: function () {
                var url = "/Home/ApplicationData";
                $.get(url, function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp); // Note: For Testing
                    vm.applications = resp;
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**My Attempt at Vue 3 Migration**

```html
<script>
  Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        applications: []
      }
    },
    created() {
        console.log('Vue App Created'); 
        this.loadModel();
    },
    methods: {
        loadModel: function () {
            var url = "/Home/ApplicationData";
            $.get(url, function (resp) {
                console.log(resp); // Note: For Testing
                vm.applications = resp;
            });
        }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<div id="app">
<ul>
    <li v-for="application in applications">{{ application.name }} - {{ application.url }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is here:

```js
vm.applications = resp;
```

The old code used `vm` to refer to the root component, but it's not assigned in your new code. However, that `vm` reference was never really necessary. It could've been avoided by using an arrow function instead of the regular function.

1. Change the `$.get` callback from a regular function into an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
2. Replace `vm` with `this`.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  ⋮
  methods: {
    loadModel: function () {
      var url = "/Home/ApplicationData";
                    1️⃣
      $.get(url, (resp) => {
          2️⃣
        this.applications = resp;
      });
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.26.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<ul>
    <li v-for="application in applications">{{ application.name }}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        applications: []
      }
    },
    created() {
        console.log('Vue App Created'); 
        this.loadModel();
    },
    methods: {
        loadModel() {
            var url = "//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
            axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp); // Note: For Testing
                this.applications = resp.data;
            });
        }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
</script>
```